# Show / hide several div

Tags: javascript

I use this script :

```
    <script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Called by :

```
            echo '<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a>';
```

i want to show / hide several div (not in a list or a form)

i try :

```
    var ele = document.getElementById("mydiv", "mydiv2");
```

but it's showing and hidding only the first div

Comment: Why is this tagged jquery? You're not using jquery anywhere. BTW, the use of the language attribute is deprecated. You should be using <script type="text/javascript"> instead.

Comment: try ele = document.getElementById("mydiv") || document.getElementById("mydiv2");

Comment: @Singh That's not what he's trying to do. He wants to handle all divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

This is not jQuery. You should use the jQuery functions to guarantee cross browser compatibilty.
Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74CRN/)

#### Sample

```
<div id="mydiv">test</div>
<div id="displayText">test2</div>

$(function() {
    $("#displayText").click(function() {
       $("#mydiv").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74CRN/)
- [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
- [jQuery.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

The getElementById() function accepts a single argument, so you cannot pass it a list of ids. There are a number of options, I suggest two of them:

- Use an array of divs and iterate through it, e.g.

  ```
  var divs = [ 'mydiv1', 'mydiv2', ... ];
  for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
      var div = document.getElementById( divs[ i ] );
      ...
  }
  ```
- Use a library such as jQuery that lets you operate on lists of items easily. In that case you could mark all your divs with an appropriate class, e.g. ***myclass***, and use something like:

  ```
  $(".myclass").hide()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use include jQuery in your page then use jQuery instead of pure javascript to make your life simpler. Try this

```
function toggle() {
    var ele = $("#mydiv");
    var text = $("#displayText");
    if(ele.is(':visible')) {
        ele.hide();
        text.html("show");
    }
    else {
        ele.show();
        text.html("hide");
    }
}
```

If you want to select multiple element in jQuyer then you can pass multiple selectors seperated by a comma.

```
var elems = $("#mydiv, #mydiv1, #mydiv2");

elems.show();//Will show all the selected elements
elems.hide();//Will hide all the selected elements
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in plain javascript, you could try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elements = [ 'mydiv', 'mydiv2' ]
foreach ( elem in elements )
{
    var e = document.getElementById(elem);
    // show/hide here
}
</script>
```